# gulp: sequential task execution

Tags: gulp

I want to compile `sass` by `gulp`, then uglify `css` for the production. When tried

```
gulp.task('build', ['sass', 'min-css'], function(){

    // ...

});
```

I had the following reporting in the console:

```
[16:44:06] Starting 'sass'...
[16:44:06] Starting 'min-css'...
[16:44:22] Finished 'sass' after 16 s
[16:44:22] Finished 'min-css' after 16 s
[16:44:22] Starting 'build'...
[16:44:22] Finished 'build' after 6.2 ms
```

As you see, `min-css` task starts before `sass` task ends. Although it was not any errors, this task sequence is incorrect. I need `sass` be complete before `min-css` starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gulp docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md) :"Note: The tasks will run in parallel (all at once), so don't assume that the tasks will start/finish in order."  So that is why your min-css task may start or finish before the sass task.

There are two main ways to fix that.

(1) Make the 'min-css' task dependent on the 'sass' task.  Something like

```
// identifies a dependent task must be complete before this one begins

gulp.task('min-css', ['sass'], function() {
    // task 'sass' is done now
});
```

(2) Use a plugin designed for this problem like 
[run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence)

> Runs a sequence of gulp tasks in the specified order. This function is designed to solve the situation where you have defined run-order, but choose not to or cannot use dependencies.

(3)  You can also try gulp4.0 which has gulp.series and gulp.parallel functions to make these things easier.  Gulp4 is technically in beta.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! `run-sequence` in the great plugin.